# Python Script to Generate a Field Based on Parameterized Calculation

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and got an interesting request.  I have a result set that is structured as such but on a much larger scale and includes multiple distinct acct. no.'s

```
acct no.   date         Event
11111111   2012/01/01   1
11111111   2012/01/05   1
```

I'm going to be attaching a secondary date object that will transform the result set into this output:

```
acct no.   date         Event
11111111   2012/01/01   1
11111111   2012/01/02   0
11111111   2012/01/03   0
11111111   2012/01/04   0
11111111   2012/01/05   1
11111111   2012/01/06   0
```

Heres the Request:

I've been asked to build a script that measures the distance between two dates, calculates the difference, in number of days and generate a flag if it falls in that distance.  The tricky part is when there is a new record set I need to append the results of the first record set onto and move onto the next and continue the calculation and flag generation.

The final output should look something like this:

```
acct no.   date         Event  Recent
11111111   2012/01/01   1      Y
11111111   2012/01/02   0      Y
11111111   2012/01/03   0      N
11111111   2012/01/04   0      N
11111111   2012/01/05   1      Y
11111111   2012/01/06   0      Y
```

I'm still relatively green in python and cant think of where to start.

Deeply appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: What is a "result set"?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it sounds like you are able to calculate the date difference and are just having trouble appending the "recent" flag to each line in the file. Assuming you're reading the account information from a text file, here's something to get you started. If your information is in a file named `accounts.txt`:

```
import shutil

recentFlag = 'Y' # Example only. It sounds like you have your own way of determining this
filename = 'accounts.txt'

shutil.copy(filename, filename+'~') # Save a backup copy of the file you're editing.
                                    # We will read from this file and write to the original


fIn = open(filename+'~', 'r')
fOut = open(filename, 'w')


header = fIn.readline() # Read the first (header) line from your file, and write it to the output file. If the real file has multiple header lines, loop this
fOut.write(header + '\tRecent')

for line in fIn:
  fOut.write(line + '\t' + recentFlag + '\n')
  fOut.flush()

fIn.close()
fOut.close()
```

Happy coding!